# How to plot axis values on the x axis in all panels in lattice in R?

Tags: r, plot, lattice, dot

I am trying to create a graph using lattice in R. I have data on four percentiles of travel time on three time periods called lag, i.e., contemporaneous, one period lag, and two-period lag. I wish to make a dot plot showing the confidence interval of percentiles of travel time corresponding to each lag. Here is my code

```
    Dotplot(percentile~Cbind(pm10,llim,ulim)|lag, data=df3, xlab=("PM 10"))
```

My data is as follows:

```
structure(list(lag = c("2 Period Lag", "1 Period Lag", "Contemporaneous", "2 Period Lag", "1 Period Lag", "Contemporaneous", "2 Period Lag", "1 Period Lag", "Contemporaneous", "2 Period Lag", "1 Period Lag", "Contemporaneous"), percentile = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("25th and 50th", "50th and 75th", "75th and 95th", "Above 95th"), class = "factor"),llim = c(-43.11, -19.29, 24.41, -52.83, -78.9, 49.33, -224.8, 
-172.27, -234.39, -91.38, 3.81, 59.46), pm10 = c(33.49, 43.55, 
76.83, 17.55, -10.97, 167.37, -103.48, -43.4, 257.91, -38.81, 
53.54, 104.45), ulim = c(110.09, 106.39, 129.25, 87.93, 56.97, 
285.41, 17.84, 85.47, 750.2, 13.76, 103.28, 149.44), se = c(39.08,32.06, 26.74, 35.91, 34.66, 60.22, 61.9, 65.75, 251.17, 26.82, 25.37, 22.95)), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

R is able to output a graph for me, but the X-axis is labelled only on one of the panels. I wish to label the X-axis in the other two panels as well. I have tried options such as alternating = False, but they do not help. These tweaks change the Y axis labels to numerics whereas the Y axis has the names of the four percentiles, i.e. c("25th and 50th", "50th and 75th", "75th and 95th", "Above 95th")

I will be grateful to you for your help.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you here unless we can see your data. Could you include the output from `dput(df3)` in your question please?

Comment: @AllanCameron I have added the data.